# Linq Select column if data exits

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have a method that returns data by viewing models from multiple tables. The problem occurs when I try to select a column while data is not exiting. Heres my code

```
public async Task<List<CustomerViewModel>> GetCustomers()
{
    return await _context.Customers.Select(x => new CustomerViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Phone = x.Phone,
        Address = x.Address,
        Payment = x.Payment,
        Due = x.Due,
        Received = x.Received,
        DateOfReg = x.DateOfReg,
        Quantity = _context.BSells.Where(_ => _.CustomerId == x.Id).Select(_=>_.Quantity).Sum(),
        Unitcost = _context.BSells.Where(_ => _.CustomerId == x.Id).FirstOrDefault().UnitPrice
    }).ToListAsync();
}
```

The problem occurs on lines 14, and 15 because the BSell table doesn't have data of the particular customer. Now, what should I do now?

I may not be able to express the problem clearly. Sorry for that.

Comment: FirstOrDefault but supply a default that contains what you want to use instead of the found customer

Comment: @pm100 sorry, I don't understand. I just trying to sum the quantity column value from the BSell table and also want's the last value from the column Unit price.

Comment: Side note, it's bad practice to use the discard operator (`_`) instead of range variables.

Comment: Thank you @GertArnold I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I've solved the issue by changing code little bit

```
public async Task<List<CustomerViewModel>> GetCustomers()
{
    return await _context.Customers.Select(x => new CustomerViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Phone = x.Phone,
        Address = x.Address,
        Payment = x.Payment,
        Due = x.Due,
        Received = x.Received,
        DateOfReg = x.DateOfReg,
        Quantity = _context.BSells.Where(_ => _.CustomerId == x.Id).Select(_=>_.Quantity).Sum(),
        Unitcost = _context.BSells.Where(_ => _.CustomerId == x.Id).Select(_ => _.UnitPrice).FirstOrDefault()
    }).ToListAsync();
}
```

I should have selected the column before taking the first value. Is it? I will be really grateful if anyone addresses my mistakes.
Thank you.

Comment: If the problem was because of the null result you could also solved it with this: `_context.BSells.Where(_ => _.CustomerId == x.Id).FirstOrDefault()?.UnitPrice`, by adding `?` that is validating if it is null, if is null it would not try to get the UnitPrice and solve the null issue.

Comment: @CristinaCarrasco This return ArgumentNullException

Comment: I see, you could also validate before it in `_context.BSells?.Where(_ => _.CustomerId == x.Id).FirstOrDefault()?.UnitPrice` because if  `_context.BSells` is null the null is coming from here and not from the `firstOrDefault`, but anyways you already solve it, thanks for trying my suggestion :)